Book request for advanced applications of partial differential equations. Particularly looking for one that covers spherical coordinates
Haberman's Applied Partial Differential Equations (which I think is a fantastic introductory book to PDEs) is the book I've been using so far, but when covering more advanced topics like Poisson's equation and Green's function, it is just shy of more advanced case that I need. I’m guessing what I’m looking for will be in more of a grad level applied math textbook, just need help picking one.
To be more specific, I’m looking for a textbook on more advanced applications Poisson's Equation and covers this PDE in spherical coordinates. Given the great difficulty of convoluting with Green's function in spherical coordinates (including in simpler cases such as this problem in polar coordinates), I'm expecting it to also provide auxiliary forms and steps to ease convolution.
Others in the physics community have recommended books on electrodynamics, but I wanted to make sure there existed a textbook for courses in mathematics which cover this more advanced problem first.

Not sure this is exactly what you are asking fore, but check out Equations of Mathematical Physics
